# Android httppost / connection / login issue

Tags: android, http-post

I have a problem connecting to database. App launches, everything seems fine, but always return me Login unseccessful - connection problem.

```
package kur.jie;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import kur.jie.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class jieActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       EditText etUser, etPass;
           Button bLogin;
        // Create string valuables
       String username, password;
       HttpClient httpclient;

       HttpPost httppost;
       ArrayList<NameValuePair> NameValuePairs;
       HttpResponse response;
       HttpEntity entity;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);          
            initialise();
        }

        private void initialise() {
            etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
            etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);
            bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
            //Now to set an onClickListener
            bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost  = new HttpPost("http://www.xxx.lt/app/login.php");

            username = etUser.getText().toString();
            password = etPass.getText().toString();         


            try {

                NameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",        username));
                NameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));


                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(NameValuePairs));

                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                if  (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
                    entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {

                    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                    String retUser= jsonResponse.getString("user");
                    String retPass= jsonResponse.getString("pass");

                    if (username.equals(retUser) && password.equals(retPass)) {

                        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("logindetails", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor spedit = sp.edit();
                        spedit.putString("user", username);
                        spedit.putString("pass", password);
                        spedit.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
                }

            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Display toast when there is a connection error
                //Change message to something more friendly
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Unsuccessful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }

        private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }//END convertStreamToString()

}
```

My php retruns json `{"id":"1","user":"xxxx@xxx.com","pass":"xxxx","long":"54.74086","lat":"25.27145","stop_id":"1","status":"+"}`

I`m loging all data which come to php file, but any data coming from app.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kur.jie"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="12" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".jieActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas?

Fanks anyway..

Comment: according to you're code there is no message login unsuccessful - connection problem, I think the way to test this, is use you're php file and prove it through the explorer sending the information on the explorer, and then looking for the answer to know if its on the same format, after that is always good to use tooglebreakpoints before the if clause so you can read what are the values that the app is retrieving from the database. if you have errors in you're log cat would be great to post them.  so we can know a little more about the problem

Comment: ` } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Display toast when there is a connection error
                //Change message to something more friendly
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Unsuccessful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

`

Comment: I`m testing on 3.1 HoneyComb.